# Does this need a preposition? He's running around (__) the second floor/basement trying to

Tags: grammar, prepositions

He's running around (__) the second floor trying to...

He's running around (__) the basement trying to...

Do these sentences need a preposition if he's running around **on the second floor** and **in the basement**?

Comment: No, you don't need a preposition there. However, you might want to use one, depending on what you are trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

Do those examples "*need*" the added preposition of "in" or "on"? No, they don't. But *may* those those examples use those added prepositions? Yes, they may. Will native speakers often *optionally* and *grammatically correctly* use those added prepositions in those contexts? Yes, they often will.

The reason is the preposition "around" doesn't require an object, like you can simply say, "He's running around," so when you say, "He's running around *on* the second floor," or, "He's running around *in* the basement," you're using the preposition "around" after "running" in a context where it doesn't require an object, but when you don't and instead just say, "He's running around the second floor," or, "He's running around the basement," you are assigning the preposition "around" an object (i.e., "the second floor" and "the basement," respectively).

So why do we sometimes add the preposition? Because saying, "He's running around the second floor," or, "He's running around the basement," is ambiguous and may be misinterpreted, signifying that he's not actually "on" the second floor or "in" the basement but is either circling said location or even avoiding it, like if I were to say, "I ran around the house," someone could just as well infer that I am not inside the house running to and fro and hither and yon but am outside the house and running in a manner that avoids it or encircles it.

Now, is such a misinterpretation unlikely in the examples you've given? Yes, it's unlikely, but preventing misinterpretation nevertheless is the basis for this manner of speaking, for why native English speakers so often as a matter of routine or habit include an additional preposition after "around," even in scenarios that would not likely or reasonably be so misinterpreted and in which the added preposition is essentially deadwood.

Comment: In the sentence, "He's running around *on* the second floor", "around" is NOT a preposition. It's a particle in the phrasal verb "run around". A preposition always has an object.

Comment: Of course, I considered that possibility *before* I wrote my answer. In fact, that's what I thought, too. But, unlike you, I wanted to be sure— so as to not speak out of school. So I looked up "run around," both in *OED* and on *dictionary.com*. It's not there, not in either. Since dictionaries list entries for phrasal verbs, that means it is **not** a phrasal verb. Check your facts *before* leaving comments like above, *before* downvoting correct answers like mine, and *before* writing contradictory answers of your own that misinform by presenting that which is **not** fact as if it were.

Comment: To be clear, if you look up "run around" in the dictionary, all you'll find is the entry for "runaround," which isn't a verb but a noun that means indecisive or evasive treatment (e.g., "I called the company to find out why my rates went up, but all I got was the *runaround*.").

Comment: I did my homework: [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-around) has an entry for it as a phrasal verb. How could you call "about" a preposition if it has no object?

Answer (score -1):

The first two examples (with nothing in the blank) use the **verb "run"** with the **preposition "around"** followed the object of "around", the place he's **running**.

The second two examples use the **phrasal verb "run around"** with the **prepositions "on" and "in"** and their objects, the places he's **running around**.

So no, the sentences do not need the prepositions "on" and "in".

The meanings are slightly different. To "*run around **(__)** the basement*" implies running **all over** the basement. To "*run around **in** the basement*" means to run around **somewhere** in the basement, maybe in just one area.

Comment: A downvote with no comment? :'(

Comment: Not my down-vote. But in both "run around the basement" and "run around in the basement", "around" is a preposition. It is not a Particle. And both mean the same thing.

Comment: @Man_From_India In, *"He's running around in the basement"*, what's the object of the preposition "about"?

Comment: you meant "around", right? And I generally say like this "complement of the preposition". Anyway in your case, off the top of my head, the verb *run* takes three complements - an intransitive preposition (*around*) and a transitive preposition along with its complement ("*in*" *the basement*).

Comment: Sorry the verb here takes two complements.

Comment: An "***intransitive preposition***"?? The only mention of it I can find means "particle". Where did you find that term? Did you make it up?

Comment: @gotobe lol no bro. I am not qualified enough to make up something that millions of linguists use :-)

Comment: https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199675128.001.0001/acref-9780199675128-e-1687